# Voice pick code

Tags: excel, hash, ascii, crc16, vba

I am relatively new to VBA coding in excel. I am trying to develop a backup system for labeling that is PTI compliant. I am wanting to establish a Voice pick code within an excel file.

I understand that the VPC calculator is a free download, but I am trying to make the VPC automatically update when a GTIN, LOT, or Date information changes in the excel file. I have been doing plenty of research and understand the formula when it is applied to JAVA. But I cant figure out how to implement it into a VBA format for excel. I understand people have already been able to create a CRC-16 Hash calculation before, but I am unable to get it to work where it matches up with the PTI voice pick calculator.

My goal is 2 create 2 functions. `=VPCS(GTIN,LOT,DATE) and =VPCL(GTIN,LOT,DATE)`. The GTIN, Lot, and date information would each be pulled out of their own cell. Then "VPCS" would gather the first 2 small numbers, while VPCL would gather the 2 large numbers of the same information. Though I'm not sure if this is even possible, if it could be done, it would help many other people who work with this kind of software.

Does anyone think this can be done? Also, just an add on, if anyone knows of any good sites in learning VBA, would you please post a link? I am trying to learn as much a possible about it.

Answer (score -2):

hi i develop a simple system on vb.net using the harvestmark voicecode.dll to print labels, but i'm not shure if this work on excel:

Imports YottaMark.Utilities.VoiceCodeLib

Public Gtin As String
 Public Lots As String
 Public Datelot As DateTime

vcode = VoiceCode.Compute(Gtin, Lots, Datelot)